# Shutdown button doesn't shut down computer on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: shutdown

I am having Latitude D520 and I installed 12.10 in which wireless card was not working so I installed 13.04 through bootable USB but shut down button is not shutting down the computer. It is getting off from OS and stopping on the black screen with following message:

```
The system is going down for power off NOW!
acpid: exiting
speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

So please someone can help me with debugging this issue?

Thanks in advavnce,
Nishant

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type in `sudo halt`?

Comment: Yes I did but I was end up with same message.

Comment: The message "The system is going down for power off NOW!" is normal, try updating your bios, maybe the acpi is buggy under Linux.

Comment: I did update the bios but still I am having same issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/287792/153378 Even these solution didn't help me to over come the above issue. Please help me.