# Not been able to Shut Down 13.04

Tags: 13.04, shutdown, acpi

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 (not upgrading to it, I did a "clean install" removing the older one), I'm not been able to shutdown the system.

After clicking the Shut Down button the desktop environment is terminated and the Ubuntu splash screen blink on the screen and a error in a black sceen (without the DE) just says the following:

```
acpid: exiting
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Comment: Try this in terminal `sudo shutdown -h -q now`.  Does your system shutdown?

Comment: Zignd, thanks. I changed property RUN from **no** to **yes** in /etc/default/speech-dispatcher then my notebook(dell inspiron 1525) shutdown successfully.

Comment: shutdown is OK but restart has same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved the problem through those steps:

I opened the terminal and with nano opened the file below:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Inside the file I changed the `RUN` property to `yes`, so the file started looking like this:

```
# Defaults for the speech-dispatcher initscript, from speech-dispatcher

# Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher
RUN=yes
```

Comment: I have this problem and this solution solve it.

Comment: This causes boot-up process to take longer, so I prefer to see the error message than waiting more seconds on startup.