# Xubuntu 13.10: I have to choose beteen: no sound Vs no shutdown

Tags: 13.10, sound, xubuntu, shutdown, volume-control

I'm running on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. I have a  funny issue, I'm currently laughing :)  I have [similar issue to this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287792/not-been-able-to-shut-down-13-04) . And Yes I was able to solve it by `RUN=yes`, otherwise, I will not be able to shut down Xubuntu.

However, when I do so, I will have no sound, I will have [similar issue to this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/), and guess what, to solve it, I have to set `RUN=no`.

So damn funny! Having to choose between never being able to shut your system down Vs never being able to hear a sound! Not sure if this is a question or a voting poll :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by disabling speech dispatcher

`sudo update-rc.d -f speech-dispatcher remove`

but now, the sound notification bar is missing, so i can't slide to change the sound, I can do so from my keyboard though.