# Is there another volume control sliding bar for Xfce?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce, volume-control, xfce-panel

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. I've recently had [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417248/xubuntu-13-10-i-have-to-choose-beteen-no-sound-vs-no-shutdown). As a result the sliding bar that is used to control the volume is gone. I can live without it, I can control the volume from my keyboard but I'd like to know if I can install an alternative to the default sliding bar.

I have Xfce4 version 4.10. My volume indicator looks like this, I don't know what it's called, but it's the default one

[image]

Comment: Looks like the old accept is no longer valid... this is the reason accepts should float after a certain point in time...

Comment: @AaronHall What should I accept now? I'm no longer on Xubuntu. Besides this question is for Xubuntu 13.10, which reached its end of life, Newer versions might have a different answer

Comment: I would remove the 13.10 tag, unaccept the current accept, and let the answers float. That would probably help the most people going forward...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the default Xfce volume slider (perhaps in Xubuntu it is default, but not in Xfce). I suspect that you're using the indicator plugin, which I don't like nor use. I would suggest that you try adding `Audio Mixer` plugin to the panel.

To have it available you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

Answer (score 9):

On Xubuntu 16.04 the `xfce4-mixer` plugin is no longer available.

Try

```
sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
```

(which is not in the `goodies` package)

Answer (score 1):

I used to replace GTK3 indicator (buggy) with the GTK2 one :

- Open with superuser rights the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service` (*Mousepad is the default file-editor in Xubuntu, replace it with Gedit or Leafpad if necessary*) :

  ```
  gksu mousepad /usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service
  ```
- Comment the existing line (comment = add a `#` at the beginning of the line) and add this line under (*This will load GTK2 indicator if XFCE is running, and GTK3 one for Gnome/Unity/Others*) :

  ```
  Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if [ -n "$(ps -U $USER | grep xfce4-panel)" ]; then /usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service;else /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service;fi'
  ```
- Your file should look like this in the end :

  ```
  [D-BUS Service]
  Name=com.canonical.indicator.sound
  #Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
  Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if [ -n "$(ps -U $USER | grep xfce4-panel)" ]; then /usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service;else /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service;fi'
  ```

---

You can also try new indicators by installing `xfce4-goodies` :

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies
```

Another indicator is, as suggested by [landroni](https://askubuntu.com/users/227922/landroni), `xfce4-mixer` :

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

Comment: there's no file called `indicator-sound.service` on my entire computer, cause i ran `whereis indicator-sound.service` and didn't return anything, certainly not in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service` and `sudo apt-get install xfce-goodies` unable to find package

Comment: My bad, it is xfce4-goodies. And for the indicator-sound.service, you SHOULD have it if you're running Xubuntu 13.10. Maybe you have an Ubuntu + XFCE instead ?

Comment: maybe because I disabled the service as indicated in the link above? or not?

Comment: the service you disabled is speech-dispatcher, it has nothing (of my knowledge) to do with sound-indicator.

Comment: I don't know, i just cant find that file, and about the goodies, I see tons of cool stuff but i see no sound indicator

Comment: I don't have Xubuntu installed anymore, but I know that this workaround was working for me on 13.10. Maybe you can try this, reboot, and if there's no change, just delete the line you added and the `#`